# SwiftUI Form sections separator

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

How could I add a separator between `sections` in a `Form`?
Is it possible in general? I tried a `divider` but it looks bad.

[image: Divider]

[image: What needed]

Above is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the divider in the footer of the section

```
Section {
    //your content
} header: {
    //your header
} footer: {
    VStack {
        Divider()
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it as well. For some reason, it looks like a tiny vertical, not a horizontal Divider.

Comment: Try wrapping the Divider in an VStack

Comment: Smart, thanks :) But the line is not really in the middle of the 2 sections. Is there a way to move it a bit lower? Sorry, just new to the SwiftUI.

Comment: use .padding(.top, value)